# Работа с SQLite из Android service

Tags: delphi, sqlite, android-service, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

У меня есть local Android service, написанный в Delphi 10 Seattle, который постоянно получает координаты устройств.

Мне необходимо накапливать эти координаты местоположения и по команде из host приложения отправлять на сервер, когда есть подключение к сети, т.к. на устройстве нет интернета.
Я думаю, координаты нужно хранить в локальной SQLite, с которой работает host.

Проблема в том, что стандартные компоненты TConnection (в том числе UNIDac) не работают в сервисе, вешают его. Вероятно, из-за наличия обращений к Android activity.
Помогите пожалуйста решить мою задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение, к сожалению, пока только для работы с UniDAC:

Обновил UniDAC компоненты для Berlin до последней версии (6.3.12).

Компоненты TUniConnection и TUniQuery отлично работают с SQLite в Android Service. FireDAC в Android Service пока запустить не удалось, но у меня самого такой необходимости нет.

В Deployment host приложения добавляю файл базы данных, Remote Path задаю ".\assets\internal\". И спокойно из сервиса получаю к нему доступ. Мой сервис локальный в одном потоке с приложением. Если делать Intent Service или Remote — наверное, придется помещать файл в другой, доступный каталог, или общаться через намерения (Intents).

Надеюсь этот код будет полезен для вас.

```
procedure TDM.conSQLiteBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
{$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  conSQLite.Database := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mybase.sqlite');
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TDM.conSQLiteError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
begin
  Log('--- DB error: %s:', [E.Message]);
  Fail := False;
end;

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Log('+ START with Intent: ' + JStringToString(Intent.getAction.toString), []);
  if Intent.getAction.equalsIgnoreCase(StringToJString('StopIntent')) then
  begin
    try
      conSQLite.Disconnect;
      Log('- DB disconnected', []);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Log('- can not to disconnect DB', [E.Message]);
    end;

    Log('... service to be stoped', []);
    JavaService.stopSelf;

    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY; // don't reload service
  end
  else
  begin
    Log('... service started', []);

    try
      conSQLite.Connect;
      Log('+ DB connected', []);

      UniQuery.SQL.Text := 'select count(*) as ALLREC from orders';
      UniQuery.Open;
      if UniQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
      begin
        UniQuery.First;
        Log('... record count: %s', [UniQuery.FieldByName('ALLREC').AsString]);
      end;
      UniQuery.Close;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Log('- can not to connect DB: %s', [E.Message]);
    end;

    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY; // rerun service if it stops
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

С FireDAC всё работает:

```
uses
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf,
  FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait;

...

var
  fdDriverLink: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
  fdConnection: TFDConnection;
  fdQuery: TFDQuery;

...

fdDriverLink := TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.Create( nil );
fdDriverLink.DriverID := 'SQLite';

fdConnection := TFDConnection.Create( nil );
fdConnection.DriverName := 'SQLite';
fdConnection.Params.Database := 'DataBaseFilePath';
fdConnection.Connected := True;

fdQuery := TFDQuery.Create( nil );
fdQuery.Connection := fdConnection;
```

Comment: Это код Android сервиса? Можно подробнее о версии IDE и FireDAC компонентов? На момент написания вопроса не работало, на каких версиях у вас работает?

Comment: Delphi Tokyo 10.2 Version 25.0.27659.1188 ну и FireDAC штатный, ничего с ним не делал. Собственно немного покапался в документации Embarcadero на их сайте и пришёл к такому коду. Да, код в сервисе.

Comment: Отлично, значит, в Токио починили